# How to align columns between two html tables?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, html-table

I have the following tables generated by ASP.net `GridView` control:

```
<!-- TOP TABLE WITH DROPDOWNS -->
<table class="taskGridView">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- BOTTOM DATA TABLE -->
<table id="yourTasksGV">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

displays this:

[image]

As you can see the first table (with the dropdown) is not aligned with the bottom table.

I have the following code on my `windows.load()` event to match each column between the two tables:

```
var firstCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:first").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:first").width(firstCol + "px");

var secondCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:second").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:second").width(secondCol + "px");

var thirdCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:third").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:third").width(thirdCol + "px");

var fourthCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:fourth").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:fourth").width(fourthCol + "px");

var fifthCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:fifth").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:fifth").width(fifthCol + "px");

var sixthCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:sixth").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:sixth").width(sixthCol + "px");

var seventhCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:seventh").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:seventh").width(seventhCol + "px");

var eighthCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:eighth").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:eighth").width(eighthCol + "px");

var ninthCol = $("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td:ninth").width();
$(".taskGridView").find("tr > td:ninth").width(ninthCol + "px");
```

When the page loads, the columns are still not aligned.

How can I modify/add to my existing code to get the desired result to be aligned for both tables? Also, how can I code it so if any of the column from either table changes, from choosing a option from the dropdown selection the columns from both table adjusts?

Comment: make them the same table?

Comment: Replace your whole Jquery code for this: `$("#yourTasksGV").find("tr > td").each(function() { $($(".taskGridView").find("tr > td")[$(this).index()]).width($(this).width()); });`

Comment: Put it in onload or ready function? I would like it to be dynamic, so anytime the size changes the other table also changes as well :)

Comment: Its just a simplified version of your code... To iterate through all columns regardless how many... You should put it on `ready`

Comment: It is not working unfortunately :/

Comment: Yes, it is: http://jsfiddle.net/hqhrbzu2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting two tables to match exactly isn't ever an easy task.  It could be done, but you'd have to track changes in either and apply them to the other at the time of change.  It's going to be a losing battle.

I'd accomplish this one of two ways:

1)  Use a plugin that gives you all the features you seem to be looking for, which will save you time and heartache, plus it will run much faster than filtering on the back end thanks to a front end data model.  My go-to is jQuery Datatables.  [Here's an example that does column filtering with inputs at the bottom](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) -- but it's easy to append the search to the top instead of the bottom if so desired.  The beauty of this method is that it's back-end agnostic, so it can run via php, java, .net, etc.

2)  If you wanted to do all the filtering via another more manual method (which I don't recommend) just make one table, and set your filters into a row with its own class that you can use for styling.

Comment: The second table is a GridView and I wasn't sure how to insert the DropDownList filtering as a second row on the GridView, that's why I added a second table above to do the filtering. For #1 how was the table generated?

Comment: Datatables can be as simple as outputting a proper html table (with thead, tbody, etc) and applying jQuery to it.  You can see the code that makes that example work at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -3):

You should use HTML's `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to keep this information aligned:

```
<!-- BOTTOM DATA TABLE -->
<table id="yourTasksGV">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: He is not creating the tables like this... It is generated by ASP.NET's `GridView`

Comment: definitely has an html tag so i thought just added it was possible.

Comment: His first statement in the question is: `I have the following tables generated by ASP.net GridView control:`